# pg_query_params equivalent in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

Is there a mysql equivalent of pg_query_params?

Answer (score 1):

Check [mysqli_prepare()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or P[DOStatement()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php). Both are a bit different, but still use a prepared statement.